# Count Down Timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a time down counter for 60 seconds in alert box. Since i am using this common.js every where in application i cannot use the Html to bind the data. so i am looking how to bind the the data in Javascript alert box only. i need to use only Javascript not jquery.

```
function idleLogout() {
    debugger;
    var timeLeft = 60;
    var t;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    function logout() {
        debugger;

        alert("Due to inactivity, your session will expire in" +timeLeft+ " seconds. Please click ‘OK’ to continue. ");
        timeLeft--;
    }
    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout, 10000);
    }
}
idleLogout();
```

Comment: `alert` stops everything until the user dismisses the dialog. By definition, while the alert box is present, no JavaScript will be executing. Thus, you cannot bind data in the alert box. Use the DOM to display your information instead.

Comment: i can't use Dom because since this function will be common for all the pages in an application.

Comment: @Abhilashm, sure you can, you can dynamically generate the DOM elements and insert them via JS.